# How to check the total memory consumed by a function in python?

Tags: python, performance, memory

I want to check the total memory consumed by a function in python. I have used tracemalloc but using it you can only check current size and peak size of memory blocks. I would like to be able to measure the memory consumed like using the @btime macro in Julia, which returns the memory allocated before returning the value of the expression.

I tried also something like this:

```
# importing libraries
import os
import psutil
 
# inner psutil function
def process_memory():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_info = process.memory_info()
    return mem_info.rss
 
# decorator function
def profile(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
 
        mem_before = process_memory()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        mem_after = process_memory()
        print("{}:consumed memory: {:,}".format(
            func.__name__,
            mem_before, mem_after, mem_after - mem_before))
 
        return result
    return wrapper
 
# instantiation of decorator function
@profile
 
# main code for which
# memory has to be monitored
def func():
    x = [1] * (10 ** 7)
    y = [2] * (4 * 10 ** 8)
    del x
    return y
 
func()
```

But this solution returns the consumed memory only at the beginning, and returns 0 on each subsequent call.

Comment: do you mean the memory in RAM the function is using?

Comment: Yes, I meant the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `memory-profiler` [library](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/).

Here an example taken from the docs:

```py
# example.py

from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    del b
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

Then in the command line type:

```bash
mprof run example.py
mprof plot
```

And you will get a table with stats and a nice looking plot:
[image]

You should easily be able to adapt this example to your function of interest.

Comment: I have a question. When I sum the Increment column, do I get the total memory consumed by the function?

Comment: sorry, my bad, but what increment column? I am not following you right now...thanks!

Comment: I mean the column returned by memory_profiler. https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

Comment: Ahh, sorry XD. As you can read from the docs "The third column (Increment) represents the difference in memory of the current line with respect to the last one. "

Comment: I know what is in this column. But I wanted to ask if by adding up the positive numbers in this column I can get the total memory used.

Comment: Yes, of course!